# Omni wheel move problem

Tags: ros-noetic, teb-local-planner

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmOOO3mZtK0&ab_channel=SimonB%C3%B8gh

https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner_tutorials/tree/melodic-devel/launch

I tried the settings above, but my robot stumbles. I want to move the angle later or less as shown in the video above.
Can you tell me which local planner to use and how to configure it?

==============================================================

https://youtu.be/ZvAjkkC-Bl0

This is a video where y-axis speed was added to the turtlebot3 settings.
It stumbles in a situation where it just needs to go straight along the x-axis and y-axis without the need for theta speed. How do I fix it?

here is my code.

```
# dwa_local_planner_params.yaml

DWAPlannerROS:

# Robot Configuration Parameters
  max_vel_x: 0.22
  min_vel_x: -0.22

  max_vel_y: 0.22
  min_vel_y: -0.22

# The velocity when robot is moving in a straight line
  max_vel_trans:  0.22
  min_vel_trans:  0.11

  max_vel_theta: 2.75
  min_vel_theta: 1.37

  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5
  acc_lim_theta: 3.2 

# Goal Tolerance Parameters
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

# Forward Simulation Parameters
  sim_time: 1.5
  vx_samples: 20
  vy_samples: 0
  vth_samples: 40
  controller_frequency: 10.0

# Trajectory Scoring Parameters
  path_distance_bias: 32.0
  goal_distance_bias: 20.0
  occdist_scale: 0.02
  forward_point_distance: 0.325
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2
  scaling_speed: 0.25
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2

# Oscillation Prevention Parameters
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

# Debugging
  publish_traj_pc : true
  publish_cost_grid_pc: true
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Please try making your question self-explanatory by adding the details instead of sharing links to video, etc. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: I edited the post. Can you help me?